# How to turn Counter results to a list of tuples

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, tuples, counter

```
example = ['apple', 'pear', 'apple']
```

How can I get the below from the above

```
result = [(apple ,2), (pear, 1)]
```

I only know how to use `Counter`, but I'm not sure how to turn the results to the format above.

The tuple command would not work:

```
>>> tuple(Counter(example))
('apple', 'pear')
```

Answer (score 6):

You can call `list` on `Counter.items`:

```
from collections import Counter

result = list(Counter(example).items())

[('apple', 2), ('pear', 1)]
```

`dict.items` gives an iterable of key, value pairs. As a subclass of `dict`, this is true also for `Counter`. Calling `list` on the iterable will therefore give you a list of tuples.

The above gives items *insertion ordered* in Python 3.6+. To order by descending count, use `Counter(example).most_common()`, which returns a list of tuples.

Comment: Or for sorted results (by count) as a single call, `Counter(example).most_common()` does all the work as a single call.

Answer (score 1):

Just do:

```
Counter(example).items()
```

Which is not a list, but if want a list:

```
list(Counter(example).items())
```

Because `Counter` is basically a dict, has equivalent functions to a dict, so Counter has `items`,

Only thing is that `Counter` has a `elements` and `most_common` (`most_common` actually can solve this), `elements` converts `Counter` to `itertools.chain` object then make to list will be the original list but ordered by occurrence.

`most_common` example:

```
Counter(example).most_common()
```

No need converting for list, it's already a list, but it orders by number of occurrence (meaning maximum --- to --- minimum).

Both Output:

```
[('apple', 2), ('pear', 1)]
```